# Efficient way of reformatting a set of characters in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been brainstorming on how reformat a set of characters in Excel. The following is a list of MAC addresses:

```
c00123837da2
c00685208b9f
c00f39fb0303
c017e60c20dc
c01de4084d1d
c020f0caf1db
c02719661782
c02b2924603d
c02f76701db5
```

I need them to be in a certain format. As an example for number one I have `c00123837da2` and I want it to be formatted as `C0:01:23:83:7D:A2`.

I would really appreciate any guidance you guys might have on how to achieve that because I have 25,000 entries to reformat.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one has `TEXTJOIN()`:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(":",,MID(UPPER(A1),{1,3,5,7,9,11},2))
```

Answer (score 1):

In `B1`, formula copied down :

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(A1),3,,":"),6,,":"),9,,":"),12,,":"),15,,":")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have `TEXTJOIN()` then try `CONCATENATE()` function. `B1` formula is

```
=UPPER(CONCATENATE(MID(A1,1,2),":",MID(A1,3,2),":",MID(A1,5,2),":",MID(A1,7,2),":",MID(A1,9,2),":",MID(A1,11,2)))
```

[image]